# Apple Live Streaming, encryption and padding to PKCS7

Tags: encryption, aes, http-live-streaming, pkcs#7

I've written a segmenter and have just added AES encryption, but I'm a little puzzled by the PKCS7 padding. When playing on the iPad, I get glitches every 12 seconds, which is my segment length.

If my file is 4 bytes short of being on a 16 byte boundary, I add `0x04 x 4`.
If it's 8 bytes short I add `0x08 x 8`.
If it's 12 bytes short I add `0x0c x 12`.
I then encrypt the package using the multiple of 16 size, is this correct?

Next question is, do I send the full encoded packet, so it's a multiple of 16, or do I send the real length (before padding)?

Comment: If you have some link to a specification of the streaming format, it might be easier to answer your question. Your padding looks good (if your packet is already full, remember adding 10 0x10 bytes).

Comment: @Paulo: just to avoid the confusion: that's _16_ bytes of value 0x10, of course.

Comment: well i have a manual decoder and everything looks good now